# Поиск среднего времени ответа на сообщение в чате с группировкой по дням

Tags: postgresql

Нужно найти среднее время ответ на первое сообщение за день и среднее время ответа на последующие сообщения за тот же день с группировкой по **creator** где **type = 1** и если пользователем было отправлено 2 сообщения подряд, то брать дату **created** для расчета среднего времени из первого вопроса

Пример

```
id                created    user      msg  type  creator
1     2019-10-14 10:00:00     103   Вопрос     0      103
2     2019-10-14 10:03:00     103   Вопрос     0      103
3     2019-10-14 10:20:00     103    Ответ     1      110
4     2019-10-14 10:21:00     103    Ответ     1      110
5     2019-10-15 11:00:00     103   Вопрос     0      103
6     2019-10-15 11:10:00     103    Ответ     1      110
7     2019-10-15 13:00:00     103   Вопрос     0      103
8     2019-10-15 13:02:00     103   Вопрос     0      103
9     2019-10-15 13:05:00     103    Ответ     1      110
```

где type = 0 (вопрос от пользователя), type = 1 (ответ на вопрос от другого пользователя)

Comment: 1) Создайте fiddle 2) Покажите эталонный ответ на этих данных с объяснением, почему именно так. *с группировкой по creator* В примере исходных данных один creator только спрашивает, другой только отвечает. Так что при группировке по creator нет ни одной пары вопрос-ответ.

Comment: 1) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8928a/4
2) Предполагается что надо найти разницу между датой создания первой записи с типом 1(ответ на сообщение) и датой создания первой записи с типом 0  (пример: 2019-10-14 10:20:00 - 2019-10-14 10:00:00)

Answer (score 0):

В первом приближении так:

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "user", type ORDER BY created ASC) rn
             FROM chat)
SELECT *, t2.created - t1.created delta
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t1."user" = t2."user"
                AND t1.rn = t2.rn
                AND t2.type = 1
WHERE t1.type = 0
```

Предполагается, что в данных нет ответов "ниоткуда".